# Mouse interrupts animation on peer-hover TailwindCSS

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have two  elements that are next to each with different information on each.  The  on the right is hidden and will slide over the first one when I hover over the first .  The transition begins to work as expected, but as soon as the emerging  reaches my mouse, it begins to flicker violently and disrupts the animation.

From a user's perspective, think of the hover effect as a 'show more' function.  I have an informational card about a city, and when I hover over it, I want to display more information and I want that additional information to slide in from the right.  A working example can be found on [www.nomadlist.com](http://www.nomadlist.com).  Hover over one of the cities and you'll see the functionality I'm looking for.

My code so far looks like this:

```
<div className="relative h-[400px] w-[300px]">
  <div className="absolute w-full h-full peer"/>
  <div className="absolute w-full h-full left-[100%] peer-hover:left-[0%]">
</div>
```

I expected the hover transition to complete regardless of the position of my mouse.  But when the transition runs into the mouse, it stop abruptly and bounces back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hungry. I see your code and the working example. Your code is correct, but some classes are missing and must be replaced. that are listed in points below

1. Use a `group` or `group-hover` instead of `peer` or `peer-hover`.
2. For a smooth hover effect, use the `transition-all` class.
3. The `duration-100` class can be used to manage transition timing.

**Note** : I've added the `bg-slate-400` and `bg-slate-800` classes for batter visualization; you can remove them if you don't need them.

**Working Example :**

```
<div className="relative h-[400px] w-[300px] group overflow-hidden">
  <div className="absolute bg-slate-400 w-full h-full"/>
  <div className="absolute bg-slate-800 w-full h-full left-[100%] group-hover:left-[0%] transition-all duration-100" />
</div>
```